# i want to print the line which starts with a paricular word and in the rest records print only 1st field

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk, scripting, stack

for eg:

```
CREATE TABLE MWWDATA."VTCat02" (
    "ID" NUMBER(10) DEFAULT NULL ,
    "Cat" VARCHAR2(255) DEFAULT NULL ,
    "Style_Code" VARCHAR2(255) DEFAULT NULL ,
    "Vendor_Style_#" VARCHAR2(255) DEFAULT NULL );
```

In the above example i want to print the line which starts with CREATE TABLE and in the rest line print only the first field.

I want output like

```
CREATE TABLE MWWDATA."VTCat02" ("ID","Cat","Style_code","Vendor_Style_#");
```

Comment: hoiw is this any different from your previous question? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240282/first-match-if-we-are-on-the-first-line-of-input-if-so-print-the-whole-line-el/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/^CREATE TABLE/{
       inside = 1
       sep = ""
       printf "%s", $0
       next
     }
     inside {
       printf "%s", sep $1
       sep = ","
       if (/\);$/) {
         print ");"
         inside = 0
       }
     }'
```

That one relies on those statements starting with `CREATE TABLE` at the beginning of the line, and ending with `);` at the end of a line (though not the same line) and each column name being the first field of subsequent lines (meaning column names can't contain blanks).

Comment: Thnk u very much @StéphaneChazelas. This is the solution what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like a job for `perl`:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's{(CREATE TABLE \S+\s+)\K(\((?:(?2)|.)*?\))}
  {"(" . join(",", $2 =~ /".*?"/g) . ")"}gse'
```

(That assumes the quoted strings don't contain unmatched parenthesis and a reasonably recent version of `perl`).

Broken down:

- `-0777`, set the record separator to 0777 (an impossible byte value), so in effect turns on the *slurp* mode where `perl` acts on the whole input as a whole.
- `-pe 'code'`: `sed` mode. (**e**valuates the code **e**xpression one record at a time and **p**rints it afterwards).
- `s{...}{...}gse`: substitute **g**lobally, treats string as **s**ingle line (`.` also matches newline characters), and the substitution is to be treated as a perl **e**xpression to **e**valuate.
- `\K`: mar**k**s the start of the part to be substituted.
- `(?2)`: one way to do recursive regexp. Here includes the regexp enclosed in the second `(...)` group. So `\((:(?2)|.)*?\)`. Is a `(` followed by a sequence of more `(...)` groups or other characters (as few as possible) followed by `)`.
- `join(",", $2 =~ /".*?"/g)` joins the list of strings that match `".*?"` (that is, quoted strings) in `$2` with a comma.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more verbose what that does (not the ned result, but how you get there). That will help other people with similar problems to adjust the answer for their future needs.

Comment: Thnx for ur response. But I need the solution using unix.

Comment: @Hennes, see edit.

Comment: @TOM, `perl` is available for all Unices and installed by default on most Unices. Please clarify what you mean by _using Unix_.

Comment: Thnx @StéphaneChazelas

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{if (NR==1) {printf "%s", $0} else {printf "%s,",$1}} END {printf "^H);\n"}' /tmp/inputfile
```

First match if we are on the first line of input, if so print the whole line, else print the first word followed by a comma.

As final step, print a backspace to get rid of the last comma and print the closing brace and a newline. The backspace character is inserted on the commandline using <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>ctrl+h</kbd>. The <kbd>ctrl+h</kbd> key corresponds to the 8th letter of the alphabet (H) and keycode 8 corresponds to a backspace.

The output will be:

```
CREATE TABLE MWWDATA."VTCat02" ("ID","Cat","Style_Code","Vendor_Style_#");
```

Comment: That `^H` does remove the comma, it just has the effect of moving the cursor backward when the output goes to a terminal.

Comment: Sure, the `printf`'s first argument should be the format. I first tried with `print` and changed it afterwards, forgot the format, changed the answer accordingly.