# First match if we are on the first line of input, if so print the whole line, else print the first word followed by a comma

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk, perl, stack

for eg:

```
CREATE TABLE MWWDATA.ACK997 (
    AKTYPE CHAR(2) DEFAULT ''  NOT NULL ,
    AKNUM CHAR(9) DEFAULT ''  NOT NULL );

CREATE TABLE MWWDATA.APREIDEXC (
    EMPLID NUMBER(15, 0) DEFAULT NULL );
```

I want output like:

```
CREATE TABLE MWWDATA.ACK997(AKTYPE,ANUM);
CREATE TABLE MWWDATA.APREIDEXC(EMPLID);
```

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What, exactly, is it that you want to do? You almost certainly don't need to remove the types from this SQL command line, but maybe might need to massage an export from a database into some other format. There are specialized tools for that, but to give you hints on that, we'd need more information...

Comment: First of all, please show us what you've tried and how it failed so we don't reinvent the wheel. Second, where is the comma you mention? Third, please [edit] and explain clearly, in the question, what you need to do.

Comment: The command i used:                                                                                     awk '{if (NR==1) {printf $0} else {printf $1","}} END {printf "^H);\n"}' inputfile
 The output i got:                                                                              CREATE TABLE MWWDATA.ACK997 (AKTYPE,AKNUM,,,,,,CREATE,EMPLID,,,,^H);

Comment: What I wanted to do is print the line that starts with "create table"  word and rest of the line that is in between " create table and semicolon(;) " prints only first word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) way

As [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) is a lot lighter than mosts alternatives, there is another solution

```
sed -ne '
    /CREATE/{h;d};
    s/^ *\([^ ]\+\) .*\()\);\? *$/\1\2/;
    ta;
    s/^ *\([^ ]\+\) .*$/\1/;
    H;
    bb;
   :a;
    H;
    x;
    s/\n//;
    s/\n/,/g;
    s/ (/(/;p ;
   :b'
```

This could be written:

```
sed -ne '/CREATE/{h;d};s/^ *\([^ ]\+\) .*\()\);\? *$/\1\2/;ta;
    s/^ *\([^ ]\+\) .*$/\1/;H;bb;:a;H;x;s/\n//;s/\n/,/g;s/ (/(/;p ;:b'
```

This will render, from you sample

```
CREATE TABLE MWWDATA.ACK997(AKTYPE,AKNUM)
CREATE TABLE MWWDATA.APREIDEXC(EMPLID)
```

Comment: Thnx, it is working....

Answer (score 0):

This `perl` script

- prints the full line (without a `\n`) if it matches `/^CREATE TABLE/`
- the first word followed by `);` and a newline if the line ends with `;`
- and the first word followed by a `,` if the line ends with a `,`.
- All other input lines are ignored.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;

while(<>) {
   chomp;
   if (m/^CREATE TABLE/) {
       print $_;
   } else {
        my @line=split ;
        if (/;\s*$/) {
            print "$line[0]);\n";
        } elsif (m/,\s*$/) {
            print "$line[0],";
        }
   }
}
```

The script's output matches what you asked for:

```
$ ./summarise.pl table.sql 
CREATE TABLE MWWDATA.ACK997 (AKTYPE,AKNUM);
CREATE TABLE MWWDATA.APREIDEXC (EMPLID);
```